# Using Quartz to round corners and apply a shadow

Tags: objective-c, uiview, quartz-graphics

There seems to be loads of thoughts on this, as well as SO questions. However, some of them say certain code works. For example:

```
[self.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 3)];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:0.9];
[self.layer setShadowRadius:3.0f];
[self.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];

[self.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];

[self.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:12.0f] CGPath]];
```

Should apply both a 12.0f corner radius and a shadow. But it doesn't work. When I use this code I get the shadow, but no corner radius.

As far as I know this is because I need to set clipsToBounds to YES. But, this in turn negates the shadow.

Am I doing something wrong or should the code above not work?

Also, people are saying a good way to get over this is to create a separate shadow layer, then add it on.

But how would I do this in a UIView's drawRect:? - Example code would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good i have tried your code and it works fine with me.

make sure `rect` used in `[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:12.0f] CGPath]]` is correct and if you are using black background then you can not see shadow.

i have tried this in my code. Here is the working code.......

```
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 5)];
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setShadowRadius:5.0f];
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setCornerRadius:12.0f];
[self.EnterQtyView.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.EnterQtyView.frame cornerRadius:12.0f] CGPath]];
```

Hope this will help you.................

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. I worked around it originally by adding a view underneath the original then decided to change my design and use a resizable image which was designed like a stack of papers instead. As you said your code works relative to my original question, I'll set it as the accepted answer though :)